# Append unique id to external survey link in email studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, email-studio, hyperlink

We're having trouble appending a unique id within the external survey link in email studio. Right now, we have the html set to a survey button:

```ampscript
%%[ Set @surveyButton = concat("[https://m.survey.bz/U75?I.Project=P2300782&ID=**YYYY**&smp=99&i.user1=3&i.user4=2&i.user3=2?][1]YYYY=", UniqueID) ]%%
```

Are we appending this unique id correctly? We're wanting to append the uniqueID in place of the "YYYY". Thank you in advance for the responses!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
%%[
var @url, @uniqueID, @finalURL
set @url = "https://www.example.com/page"
set @uniqueID = GUID() /* Generate a unique ID using the GUID() function */
set @finalURL = Concat(@url, "?id=", @uniqueID)
]%%

<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@finalURL)=%%">Click Here</a>
```